# using url manager in yii to change url to seo friendly

Tags: yii, seo

How can I convert these URL to SEO  friendly URL I tried Url manager in yii but didn't get the proper result is there any good tutorial regarding url manager

```
http://localhost/nbnd/search/city?city=new+york
http://localhost/nbnd/search/manualsearch?tosearch=Hotel+%26+Restaurants+&city=New+york&yt0=Search&searchtype=
```

I tried to the following setting in url manager

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<city:\d>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

which works with url `http://localhost/nbnd/search/city/city/Delhi`

I wish to reduce this url to `http://localhost/nbnd/search/city/Delhi`

and the link I generating in my view is `<?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->city), array('/search/city', 'city'=>$data->city)); ?>`

This generates link as `http://localhost/nbnd/search/city?city=Delhi`
How can I convert that link to like `http://localhost/nbnd/search/city/Delhi`

Comment: did you read [the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url)?

Comment: @bool.dev I read it thoroughly but didn't get the expected results its working but not accurately.

Comment: ok, then put up the details of how & what you have tried, what are your expected results, what do you mean by working accurately. be specific, and you'll get specific answers.

Comment: @bool.dev I added my problem have a look please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rule should be (to remove the extra city, which is the GET parameter name):

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<city:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>', // not city:\d, since Delhi is a string, not digit
```

So the rule should be able to match the parameter name, incase you had foo/Delhi, you'd use `<foo:\w+>`.

And to remove the `?` use [`appendParams` of `CUrlManager`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager#appendParams-detail), (in your `urlManager` config):

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'appendParams'=>true,
    // ... more properties ...
    'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<city:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        // ... more rules ...
    )
)
```

When `appendParams`

> is true, GET parameters will be appended to the path info and separate from each other using slashes.

---

Update: Incase you have more than one parameter being passed to the action i.e:

```
http://localhost/nbnd/search/manualsearch/Delhi?tosearch=restaurants
```

Use a `/*` at the end of the rule:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<city:\w+>/*'=>'<controller>/<action>'
```

To get urls of form:

```
http://localhost/nbnd/search/manualsearch/Delhi/tosearch/restaurants
```

Comment: on reading your question again, i realized you might also be looking for cases when you have more than one parameter, like in your manualsearch action, so i have added details for that, be sure to follow up

Comment: @bool-dev thanks for this its working fine but now I am stuck with some other issues on the same please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893728/url-parameters-values-with-special-characters-are-providing-errors-in-view

Answer (score 1):

In Yii we can create urls dynamically For eg.

```
$url=$this->createUrl($route,$params);
$route='post/read'.
$params=array('id'=>100)
```

we would obtain the following URL:

```
/index.php?r=post/read&id=100
```

To change the URL format, we should configure the urlManager application component so that `createUrl` can automatically switch to the new format and the application can properly understand the new URLs:

```
array(
    ......
    'components'=>array(
        ......
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
        ),
    ),
);
```

WE will obtain this

```
/index.php/post/read/id/100
```

You can refer this link for user friendly urls in yii
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Comment: but how can I manage when I have two variables or when instead of ID I am using any name or any other variable

Comment: you can add as many variables you like provided your function inside controller handles it. For eg. if you want to add name variable as an extra param then in the params array include name like $params=array('id'=>100,'name'=>'bct'). And the result will be /index.php/post/read/id/100/name/bct. Note your function should be actionRead($id,$name)