# Url parameters values with special characters are providing errors in view

Tags: yii, yii-components

I have edited Url manager to provide SEO friendly urls but getting problem when the url have values with special characters such as `. or () or - or any other special character`

```
http://localhost/nbnd/search/city/delhi

In city action
var_dump($_GET);

output: array(1) { ["city"]=> string(6) "delhi" } 

but when url is with some special character
http://localhost/nbnd/search/city/north-delhi or
http://localhost/nbnd/search/city/north.delhi or
http://localhost/nbnd/search/city/(north)delhi

In city action
var_dump($_GET);

Output : array(1) { ["north-delhi"]=> string(0) "" } 
and so for other
```

this change in array values results in error.

Comment: what are the characters that you want to allow?

Comment: @bool.dev i want all them it was working earlier with default url but it didn't work with SEO formatted urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want all sorts of characters, change your rule from the related [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13882286/720508):

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<city>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
// omit the pattern \w+ from city:\w+
```

[Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-named-parameters):

> In case when ParamPattern is omitted, it means the parameter should match any characters except the slash /.